# Issue positioning popper tooltip inside scaled iframes

Tags: css, iframe, popper.js, react-popper

I'm having issue positioning popper on a scaled iframe element.
In the screenshot you can see that the element is wrongly positioned both on the X and Y axis. The scale is applied with a css rule `transform: scale(x)`

[image: I'm having some prob]

In this sandbox you can reproduce the issue using `@popperjs/core` `2.11.6`

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-haze-197srf?file=/index.html

I can see that the iframe scaling should be handled here:
https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/blob/db4b7ad129b3f79b85184c3c30f352daab824cc3/packages/dom/src/utils/getBoundingClientRect.ts#L61

Is this a known limitation of Popper v.2? Any known workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a know limitation of Popper v2.

The issue is resolved using `floating-ui` v1 as explained here:
https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/issues/2184